# How to draw bar chart of part of the table in ggplot

Tags: r

I have a df and now I want to draw part of this table eg the first 4 comp using a bar chart in ggplot, x is their name and y is their weight, how can I do this? really thanks.
here are the data, and I can draw the bar chart by barplot(proportion[1:5]), but I don't know how to do it using ggplot.

```
Comp.1     Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4     Comp.5     Comp.6     Comp.7     Comp.8     Comp.9 
0.40621148 0.11918044 0.10076079 0.09143389 0.07362891 0.07093344 0.05213663 0.03896318 0.03318098 
Comp.10 
0.01357027
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get a better response if you provide some example data (in a plain text format) and an indication of what you have tried already to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have edited and add the plain text of data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot` works best when data is "long" - 1 column per variable, 1 row per observation. You can reshape your data using `tidyr::gather()`. Note that `gather` is being replaced by `pivot_long`, but it still works for now.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

mydata <- read.table(text = "Comp.1     Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4     Comp.5     Comp.6     Comp.7     Comp.8     Comp.9 Comp.10 
0.40621148 0.11918044 0.10076079 0.09143389 0.07362891 0.07093344 0.05213663 0.03896318 0.03318098 0.01357027",
header = TRUE)

mydata %>%
  gather(Var, Val)

       Var        Val
1   Comp.1 0.40621148
2   Comp.2 0.11918044
3   Comp.3 0.10076079
4   Comp.4 0.09143389
5   Comp.5 0.07362891
6   Comp.6 0.07093344
7   Comp.7 0.05213663
8   Comp.8 0.03896318
9   Comp.9 0.03318098
10 Comp.10 0.01357027
```

So one way to plot the first 4 rows:

```
mydata %>% 
  gather(Var, Val) %>% 
  head(4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var, Val)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Note that the columns are ordered correctly when using only 1-4, but you may have to reorder them when other numbers are used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps, I thought the reason why I cannot do it before is I don't how to write x and y in aes part, your code really helps solving my question, I am a beginner using R and gather is the first time I hear, thank you so much!